# (Big Question) Logic in Mathematics

Tags: logic

Prior to body, willing to note that this question would not be proper because of too vagueness of it.

Today I had met a person and been questioned below:

1) What is logic in mathematics?

2) Is it natural? never be dependent on "Human" ?

3) How does the mathematical society discern the logical consistency about a given proof? Is there any kind of agreement regarding "What the logic is" or does it depend on social agreement such as people do in social science or study of laws?

Comment: a) The language of mathematics is based on formal logic and set theory. b) Its formal logic. Define ''human'' here. c) No agreement if you ask me.

Comment: You may find [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics/) and [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/) interesting.

Comment: Isn't [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) the right place for that kind of question ?

Comment: @Wuestenfux so mathematics concerns about formal logic only?

Comment: Have you done any research on these questions today, after having "been questioned"?  Did you search google for "What is the logic in mathematics?"  Or any of the other questions?  This isn't so much vague as it is far to broad, and deals largely with philosophy.  I must therefore vote to close as off topic, for lack of research, and for the fact that these questions are philosophical, more than they are mathematical.